# Trouble finding string followed by variable whitespace and numbers in R with regex

Tags: r, regex

I'm attempting to use some regex to find the lines in a series of documents so I can accurately subset the information. First, some sample data.

```
text <- c("BAR                  02/      BLAHBLAH                                                 ",
      "                       27/      LOCATION: BLAH-TOWN",
      "                      2013      BLAH;BLAH",
      " BAR         09/       10/      BOOHAABLAH                 ",
      "             25/       14/      LOREM IPSUM,                        ",
      "             2014      2014     LOREM LORE LOT",
      " BAR         BLAH MUH BLAH NO BLAH")
```

I am attempting to find the element of the list where BAR is followed ONLY by numbers. The number of whitespaces is variable, but the lines I am interested in capturing are always followed by numbers. I am using the base R grep() function and have tried  a large number of functions.  No positive lookahead configuration I have found so far seems to catch it?

Some of the things I have tried so far.

`grep("(BAR\\b(?=\\s*[0-9]))", text, perl= T)`

`grep("(BAR\\b(?=\\s*\\b[0-9]))", text, perl= T)`

`grep("(BAR\\b\\s*\\d\\d\/)", text, perl = T)`

`grep("BAR\\s*[0-9]",text,perl=T)`

`grep("BAR\\s*(?![^A-Za-z])",text,perl=T)`

Where am I going wrong? I've heard some about tidyr, but none of what I've read on it shows any more promise than grep.

Comment: What is wrong with your first `grep`? It [looks working](https://regex101.com/r/PgF6b0/1).

Comment: When I execute it, it returns zero matches.  I don't know why it doesn't work, because it seems like it should.  When I take off the [0-9], it returns all lines with BAR in it, but once I put the [0-9] in, it returns NULL

Comment: @JordanCole I get elements 1 and 4.

Comment: It should work but you have to take out the `\b` because you don't need it. And, if you leave it in, it will never match BAR9.

Comment: It means you have some Unicode spaces between. Try either `grep("BAR[[:space:]]+[0-9]", text)` or `grep("(*UCP)BAR\\s+[0-9]", text, perl=TRUE)`. I suspect there must be at least one whitespace between the BAR and digit. Else, you need `\s*` without `\b`s (see sln's comment).

Comment: Try changing "BAR" to "VIOL". The string I am chasing is actually VIOL, but when I swap out VIOL and BAR, I go from having 2 matches to 0 in R.

Comment: If it doesn't find it, then it's not there. Ever thought of that ?

Comment: @JordanCole Please add all relevant code to the question.

Comment: If I execute the above code, it works fine. I get 1 and 4.  If you change "BAR" to "VIOL" (this is the string I am actually trying to extract), it breaks.

Regardless, the second query you provided worked wonders. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: So, the actual input contains Unicode spaces, right? Does `grep("(*UCP)VIOL\\s+[0-9]", text, perl=TRUE)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide the answer based on [your feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183910/trouble-finding-string-followed-by-variable-whitespace-and-numbers-in-r-with-reg#comment79331135_46183910). It appears you modify the character vector by changing `BAR` to `VIOL` and **introduce Unicode whitespace** into the string.

Thus, the following should work in your case:

```
grep("(*UCP)VIOL\\s+[0-9]", text, perl=TRUE)
```

The `(*UCP)` PCRE verb will make `\s` match any Unicode whitespaces.

In other environments (this is not your case), where TRE (default base R regex engine) POSIX character classes are Unicode aware, one might also use

```
grep("VIOL[[:space:]]+[0-9]", text)
```

Comment: This solves the problem.  I also didn't know about (*UCP) PCRE verb, so thank you very much Wiktor.

Comment: Glad to help. What is still a mystery is why sometimes PCRE regex works better for Unicode strings than both TRE (default base R) and ICU (stringr).